# Difference between 'goapp deploy' and 'appcf.py' to deploy my app on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, deployment

I don't understand the difference between

```
goapp deploy -application <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> myapp/
```

and

```
appcfg.py -A <YOUR_PROJECT_ID_> -V v1 update myapp/
```

when trying to deploy my app in google app engine. Can somebody enlighten me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documented in [Uploading, Downloading, and Managing a Go App](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadinganapp):

> `goapp deploy` wraps the `appcfg.py` python tool provided in the SDK. You can also invoke this tool directly if you need greater control over the deployment.

`goapp deploy` is equivalent to `appcfg.py update myapp/`.

These commands get application ID and other configuration from `app.yaml` automatically. You can use `-application` param of `goapp`, or `-A` of `appcfg.py` to override the application ID.

---

So `goapp deploy` calls `appcfg.py` under the hood, it is a convenient method to hide `appcfg.py`.

```
goapp deploy -application <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> myapp/
```

Deploys the application located in the `myapp` folder. Configuration will be read from the `app.yaml` file that must be at `myapp/app.yaml`. The command also overrides the application ID (if present in `app.yaml`), and `<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>` will be used instead.

```
appcfg.py -A <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> -V v1 update myapp/
```

This also deploys the application, but the `-V` overrides the version that may be present in `myapp/app.yaml`, and will use the version `v1`. `-A` is used to override the ID from `app.yaml`, will be `<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`goapp` is a general tool for the whole Go-on-App-Engine workflow from build to deployment; you can use the same tool to install dependences (`get`), `build` your app, run locally (`serve`) and then `deploy` it (as well as run tests, format code, etc).

Some of these wrap other tools: `goapp fmt` probably just wraps `gofmt`, whilst `goapp deploy` just wraps `appcfg.py update` (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadinganapp#Go_Uploading_the_app))